# Lazy load with MEF?

Tags: c#, .net, import, lazy-loading, mef

Take a look at this code :

```
public class Program
{
[import]IMain Main {get; set;}
...
private Compose() {...}
}

internal interface IMain
{
...
}

[Export(typeof(IMain)]
public class Main : IMain
{
  [import]
  Interace1 Object1 {get;set;}

  [import]
  Interace2 Object2 {get;set;}
}
...
```

I want to lazy load Object2 after the composition beween Program and Main. When I compose in Program, I've a MEF error because MEF try to compose Object2 as well (but the implementation of Interface2 is not available at the begining... I want to load it after).

How can I do this ?

I've tried to put :

```
 [import]
  Lazy<Interace2> Object2 {get;set;}
```

but I still have the same trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
[Import(AllowDefault=true, AllowRecomposition=true)]
Lazy<Interface2> Object2 {get;set;}
```

AllowDefault will allow the composition to succeed when there is no Interface2, and AllowRecomposition will allow you to add it later.  It doesn't matter if you use a property of type `Lazy<Interface2>` or just `Interface2` in this case.

Comment: In this case, which value is null when `Interface2` is not available? Is `Object2` null, or is `Object2.Value` null?

Comment: I ran some tests and concluded that `Object2` would be null in this case. So the null-annotated form of this import would be: `Lazy<Interface2>? Object2 { get; set; }`.